# What are the pros and cons of using embedded documents versus arrays in mongoid?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

What are the pros and cons of using embedded documents when you can simply use an array datatype? Both seem similar to me (and I couldn't find any information online via google search). Please provide example cases!

Comment: Arrays are arrays - untyped vectors of data. With embedded documents you get more support from the library (mongoid).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In terms of data structures, you can think of *embedded documents* as [hashes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) or dictionaries .. while *arrays* are a list of values.

With embedded documents in MongoDB:

- embedded documents have named fields, and can embed other documents for rich data representation
- you can reference fields directly using [dotted notation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29)
- creating an index on an embedded document field only indexes that field
- you can use [field selection](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Querying#Querying-FieldSelection) to retrieve a subset of fields.

With arrays in MongoDB:

- you can manipulate arrays using [operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operators) such as `$push`, `$pop`, `$pull`, and `$addToSet`.
- you can match array values using operators such as `$all`, `$in`, `$nin`.
- you can also use [multikey indexes](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Multikeys)
- creating an index on an array element indexes each element of the array.
- you can use the [`$slice` operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields#RetrievingaSubsetofFields-RetrievingaSubrangeofArrayElements) to retrieve a subset of an array.

Mongoid's notion of [relations](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html) express a few different combinations of embedded documents and arrays:

- embeds_one - a single embedded document
- embeds_many - an array of embedded documents